# Can't update Node?

Tags: node.js

Node Version: v5.12.0
When I try and update node, it says it updates, but when I do (node -v) it states the (v.5.12.0) version. I tried uninstalling using (sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm) then I do not know what to do from there.

Getting pretty frustrated, since everytime I uninstall and try and reinstall it installs the old version.

Comment: You probably have multiple copies of node in your path.  One is updating, but that isn't the first one in your path.  You need to find out where the one that isn't updating is located and probably remove it or change your path to not include it.

Comment: I used to stuck with node version updating, but later I found [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) , it made my life easier :) !

Comment: How do I install that?

Comment: the URL I gave you above has documentation includes installation guide, lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install -y lsb-release
sudo apt-get install -y  curl 
sudo apt-get update

wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -O  setup.sh 
chmod 755 setup.sh
sudo  ./setup.sh
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Use This Commands

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove all the instances of nodejs. For a fresh new install. 
Since you will get a version that you want.

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

Then install `nvm` which is the best tool to install nodejs and npm.

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

Update your bash

```
source ~/.profile
```

The below code will install the node version 6.11.5
Or check the github page of **node version manager(nvm)**

```
nvm install v6.11.5
```

The above command is going to install **node version 6.11.5** 
Just type in the version you want to get it installed.

Now you will have a node version that you wanted to use